# Automatically send to "Post" or "Page" Wordpress plugin Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, plugins, action, hook, contact-form-7

I want that submission from CF7 automatically gets posted to "Post" or a "Page" on my site.

I saw that it is necessary to add some action hook but I do not have the skills to do that? Can someone help me out please?

Thank you!

edit: I could do it with Blog_by_Email service (which sends submission to some email and then make a post automatically), but I need user id on the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the wp_insert_post to do this

```
  //sample code
 if(isset($_POST['submit_button'])){
  $my_post = array(
    'post_title' => $_POST['title'],
    'post_date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
    'post_content' => $_POST['description'],
    'post_status' => 'pending',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_author' => $user_id
    );
 $the_post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}
```

for more info about wp_insert_post visit this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Comment: does it matter where in wp-includes/post.php do I put it?

Comment: you can post it in your template

Comment: do I change anything.. I dont quite understand, sorry. can you explain a little please

Comment: do you know the template your form located?

Comment: I have the basic skills.. I should put this code in the script that executes the form submit?

Comment: Right but you have to change the $_POST parameter in relation to your form for it to work..

Comment: ok.. in CF7 the fields are named like that [date], [time], etc... How do I put them in this code.. like ['date'], ['time'],...? and if I want to put in the 'post_content' more fields how do I do that, like this- ['time'],['date'] or ['time,date']